# iOS - Filtering and forwarding touches to subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

The application I'm building has a full-screen `MKMapView`, with another `UIView` subclass placed over it, full-screen as well and completely transparent. I would like for the `UIView` subclass to handle single touch gestures, such as taps and single finger drags, and ignore anything else. This would allow the `MKMapView` to be interacted with using other means, especially panning/scrolling with two fingers by disabling 3D functions.

My issue here is that MKMapView does not use the `touchesXXX:withEvent:` methods for its user interaction. So, I can't detect touch count in those methods on the view and forward to the map. Likewise, the `hitTest:withEvent:` method can't be used to determine which view handles the touches, because the `UIEvent` object there returns an empty set of touches.

I've considered letting all touches forward through the view and using a gesture recognizer to handle events, but I really need the single touch/drag on the overlay view to have no effect on the map view.

Is there a way to accomplish this filtering based on the number of touches? Or a way to disable the single touch gestures on the map view?

Comment: Does it work if you attach single finger tap and drag recognizers to the mapview itself?

Comment: So basically overriding/canceling existing gestures on the map view by replacing them?

Comment: Yes. One second, I'm looking at this in Xcode.

Comment: I just tried it as well and it seemed to have no effect.. gesture was never called (seemed the map view's recognizers swallowed the gesture first)

Comment: Me too. Even setting them on the parent view.

Comment: Just figured it out. See answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this is actually very simple.

- Give the map view a parent view that it fills completely
- Give the parent view pan and tap gesture recognizers configured to only respond to one finger touches
- On the `MKMapView`, set the `scrollEnabled` property to `NO` (the "Allows Scrolling" checkbox in IB)

The gesture recognizers allow you to get the gestures, and setting `scrollEnabled` to `NO` prevents the MapView from swallowing the pan gestures.

Sample project here: https://github.com/Linux-cpp-lisp/sample-no-gesture-mapview

Comment: Very nice. I like it, and it's so close. This just introduces one issue - when you disable the 3D functions of the map, a two-finger gesture allows the map view to be scrolled, which is what I'm looking to do really (I guess I should have specified that I apologize). Now the unfortunate part is that disabling scrolling to swallow single touch gestures doesn't allow the two-finger pan to scroll :(

Comment: I'm currently testing a bunch along these lines to come up with some state that allows this functionality using gestures. It has to be possible. I think you're on the right path, thanks!

Comment: @bgoers: Sure. One thing you could try is doing the scrolling yourself by also capturing two finger pans and calculating offsets. Not quite sure how to do that though.

Comment: That was my last resort plan, if there is nothing I can do with forwarding/canceling gestures :)

Comment: @bgoers: Take a look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mapkit/reference/mkmapview_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008205-CH3-SW6) section of the `MKMapView` docs. It might not be that hard to convert the current region to a rect, offset the rect by the pan, convert that rect back to a region, and set it as the map region.

Comment: Seems like a very easy way to do it, and probably the simplest at this point. I'm gonna go ahead and accept your answer as well, as it generally provides a way to accomplish some sort of similar mechanism

Comment: @bgoers: Thanks. Glad I could be of help.

Comment: just wanted to update - using gestures on the overlay view was the simplest and most effective way to accomplish this. It's very easy to do some math and manually scroll the map view :)

Comment: Great! Hope your project (whatever it is) continues to go well.